# Windows 10 File Explorer video/audio track columns disappeared?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I've just noticed they've been removed from the default file explorer on my Windows 10 machine, and when choosing columns they no longer appear in the list.

Only thing I can think of recently that might affect is was the following update:

```
Feature update to Windows 10, version 1803 x64 2019-07B
Successfully installed on ‎13/‎07/‎2019
```

I've tried researching via google, but couldn't find update notes that refer to it or similar queries anywhere else. Therefore I am stuck. If it's just the case that it will come back when 1903 is available for my machine then fantastic, but there's no date given for when that will be.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Windows 10 1903: "Audio tracks" and "Video tracks" are there.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What research have you done? Where have you got stuck? [superuser.com/help/how-to-ask](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Albin, updated :)

Comment: whats the exact name of the column you are looking for? where did you find the info that those columns are removed in the 1803 update?

Comment: An educated guess as I recall using them before the rough time that was installed. They're also not present on a different machine with 1809 installed. Video track & audio track were the names I think, listing the codecs e.g. mp4/mkv or aac/ac3